# How can I change an app title in eclipse within the main.java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

What I'm trying to do is create a very simple app that displays "Welcome to Android, [NAME]!" as a text field and as the app's title. However, I want the app to display this only after pressing a button and if the user leaves the field blank then "Welcome to Android" is displayed. I managed to get the button and text to display properly, just not the title. I've tried looking all over the web for an answer but only came across a method using string.xml. How can I write the java code to change the app's title?

Here is what I have so far:

```
package com.helloandroidbutton;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/**Called when activity is created. */
private Button btn;
private EditText edit;
private TextView view;
private RelativeLayout title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    title = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.string.app_name);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(btn==v){
        if(edit.getText().toString().equals("")){
            String msg ="Welcome to Android!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              toast.show();
              view.setText(msg);
                              //This was my attempt to change the title
              /*title.setText(msg);*/
        }
        else{
            String msg ="Welcome to Android, " + edit.getText() + "!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              toast.show();
              view.setText(msg);
              /*title.setText(msg);*/


    }


}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(btn.getId()==v.getId())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance. After many hours, I figured I had to use setTitle().